# Cannot boot my ubuntu after upgrade to 15.10

Tags: boot

I cannot access  my computer using Ubuntu after upgrading to 15.10.If I attempt to access my files from recovery mode, it needs me to login and just shows `#boot`. How can I fix my installation?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please help us help you by providing a bit more detail. Review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the details that you have given, I believe that the best option is to boot from a USB, copy all of your important files onto there, and then preform a fresh install of Ubuntu (Latest.) To do so, please follow the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).